# How to check if "app" is substring of "gapple" in progress openedge 4gl?

Tags: string, substring, progress-4gl, openedge

I need to check if "app" is substring of "gapple" or not. I know I can do it using `matches` but I think its expensive.

Seems `lookup` and `can-do` match the whole string?

Comment: Any string manipulation you do on a search statement (for or find) will compromise speed anyway. You might get a better performance if you have a word-index for the field you wish to issue these matching queries, and as pointed by Jens in his reply, INDEX is your friend, though MATCHES can also do the trick, as you mentioned in the question itself. Lookup is more used for csv's and can-do is supposed to be used for permission, not for text. But it does take wildcards.

Comment: a word index won't work, you can only have wildcards at the end of the word. contains "app*" doesn't match "gapple"

Answer (score 4):

You can use `INDEX`, it searches for a string within a string.

```
DISPLAY INDEX("gapple", "app").
```

Full usage:

> INDEX(source, target [, starting position]).
>
> Returns an INTEGER value that indicates the position of the target string within the source string. If you specify a starting position you start from that position and search right.
>
> If the string isn't present INDEX will return a 0.

If you want to search right-to-left you can use `R-INDEX` with the same inputs.

**About functions and queries**

You should if possible avoid to use functions like `INDEX` in queries. It will make index matching not work and result in table scans (reading of entire tables/indices). Depending of size of table it will potentially take up lots of resources.

**Don't do this:**

```
FOR EACH table NO-LOCK WHERE INDEX("searchstring, table.field) > 0:
```

**Instead:**

Find a work around. The work around must be adapted for your system and could be one of the following (or something else):

- Adding a field to your table where you nightly scan the table and update the search result.
- Transfering a limited number of records to a temp-table and then scanning it (but remember: temp-table index usage counts too).
- Limiting the query with other clauses and then running INDEX only on those. The  example below will scan all todays records but not the rest.
- Something entirely different that works for you!

Example:

```
FOR EACH table NO-LOCK WHERE table.date = TODAY: 
    IF INDEX("searchstring, table.field) > 0 THEN DO:
        /* Code goes here */
    END.
END.
```

*Edit: after good comments I added some information about using functions in queries*

Answer (score 1):

As JensD points out "index()" is the usual function for that purpose.

If you are concerned about it being expensive that suggests that you might be thinking about using it in a WHERE clause.  Using any function in a WHERE clause is going to be expensive because you are going to force the engine to examine a whole lot of data.

CAN-DO() is especially dangerous in that regards.  While it is often subverted as a string function it is actually a client-side  **security** function.  One of the side-effects of that is that it cannot be evaluated by the db engine -- it must be evaluated on the client.  So all data that can-do() looks at must be passed to the client.

You will find plenty of bad examples to follow but you should **not** use can-do() as a string function and you should especially not use it in WHERE clauses.

Comment: Good points. Since no queries was mentioned I didn't think about table scanning and such.